# Python regex finditer into dictionary

Tags: python, regex

Pretty new to programming, so apologises in advance for any lack of knowledge on my part.

In process of trying to extrapolate the directory number of a phone and its MAC address which I've provided some sample data below, and put into the variable of LLDPLarge:

```
LLDPLarge = '''* Slot-1 Far-B65-2ND.1 # show lldp neighbours detailed | include (System Name: "regDN |: 08:00:0F)

  Port ID     : 08:00:0F:36:46:62
- System Name: "regDN 7335,MITEL 5340 IP"
  Port ID     : 08:00:0F:3E:56:1C
- System Name: "regDN 7383,MITEL 5340 IP"
  Port ID     : 08:00:0F:3C:12:B2
- System Name: "regDN 7270,MITEL 5340 IP"
  Port ID     : 08:00:0F:28:9C:22
- System Name: "regDN 7320,MITEL 5340 IP"'''
```

The code I have come up with is as follows:

```
vartest1 = "(?<=System Name: \"regDN )(.*)(?=,)"
vartest2 = "([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})"
vartest3 = vartest1 + "|" + vartest2

for match in re.finditer(vartest3, LLDPLarge):
    sGroup = match.group()
    print('{}'.format(sGroup))
```

This is a sample of the output it creates, which is pretty close to what I want:

```
08:00:0F:36:46:62
7335
08:00:0F:3E:56:1C
7383
08:00:0F:3C:12:B2
7270
08:00:0F:28:9C:22
7320
```

What I would like to do is output it to a dictionary as follows:

```
'08:00:0F:36:46:62' : '7335'
'08:00:0F:3E:56:1C' : '7383'
'08:00:0F:3C:12:B2' : '7270'
'08:00:0F:28:9C:22' : '7320'
```

At this time I'm not sure how to go about this or if my code is the most elegant?

Any help most appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `group(1)` or `group(2)` is filled in. If `group(1)` has a value then the regexp matched the phone number, otherwise it matched the MAC address. Then you can use it as the key or value of the dictionary.

```
d = {}
for match in re.finditer(vartest3, LLDPLarge):
    if match.group(2):
        key = match.group()
    else:
        val = match.group()
        d[key] = val

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from re import finditer
from itertools import islice

# LLDPLarge = ...

pattern_system = "(?<=System Name: \"regDN )(.*)(?=,)"
pattern_port = "([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})"
pattern = f"{pattern_system}|{pattern_port}"

d = {key.group(): value.group() for key, value in zip(*[finditer(pattern, LLDPLarge)] * 2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
# Make a list with all the strings
everything = [match.group() for match in re.finditer(vartest3, LLDPLarge)]
# Pick every other one to get a list of just the MAC addresses
macs = everything[0::2]
# Same thing for the names
names = everything[1::2]

# Make a blank dictionary
dict = {}
# Fill the dictionary from our lists
for i in range(0, len(macs)):
    dict[macs[i]] = names[i]

print(repr(dict))
```

The itertools solutions are more elegant than this, but this requires less python expertise to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If `LLDPLarge` is your string from the question, then this example:

```
import re

d = dict(re.findall(r'([\dA-F:]{17}).*?regDN (\d+)', LLDPLarge, flags=re.S))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'08:00:0F:36:46:62': '7335', '08:00:0F:3E:56:1C': '7383', '08:00:0F:3C:12:B2': '7270', '08:00:0F:28:9C:22': '7320'}
```